# I want to parse through the log in Jenkins and place it in a .csv file

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I want to parse through the log in Jenkins and place it in a .csv file. I have tried

```
 mkdir BlackDuck_Results

 type log | .\BuildTools\gawk -f    
.\BuildTools\blackDuck.gawk>.\BlackDuck_Results\blackduck.csv
```

However, it doesn't find the log and I cannot get it from the master.

I have also tried writing a groovy script

```
if(manager.getLogMatcher(/(File count with Pending ID \:) [1-9]+/))
{ println "found it" }
if(manager.getLogMatcher(/(LicenseViolationCount\:) [1-9]+/)) {
println "found it" }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But there are several ways to access the running console log (same as when you click *console output* link.

Enter the following into the URL for any of your existing builds:
`http://[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/lastBuild/api/`
and it will give you a page explaining this.

Progressive log:
`http://[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/lastBuild/logText/progressiveText?start=0`

Static log:
`http://[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/lastBuild/consoleText`

If you are using *nix, you can get the any of the above with something like:
`wget http://[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/lastBuild/consoleText | cat consoleText`